# shape recognition on picture taken from webcam

Tags: c#, image

i would like to extract information is there a human hand on some photo taken from local webcam.
I get how to extract light information, find brightest points or few of them, but how to recognize shape on some image?

I have started C# project, and I'm using AForge library to apply some filters to captured images, but I'm pretty stuck with shape recognition.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a look at the image recognition project over at codeplex.

http://www.codeplex.com/IR

It is an open source .NET project written in c#.  It should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [OpenCV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1WNb0g0f9Q), using haar cascades.

There's even a classifier readily available for non-commercial use - see http://code.google.com/p/ehci/wiki/HandTracking